# Angular Factory data empty after $http

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to store data into a location[] array via http request method to a json file.

The problem is my listings controller always contains an empty array.

**My Factory**

```
app.factory('listing__data', function($http, $q){
  return {
    locations: '',
    makeRequest: function(url) {
      // Create the deffered object
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http.get('/'+url).then(function(resp) {
        deferred.resolve(resp.data);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    },
    getUrl: function(params) {
      var url = "locations.json";

      if(!this.locations) {
        this.locations = this.makeRequest(url);
      }
      // Return the myObject stored on the service
      return this.locations;
    }
  };
});
```

**My Controller**

```
var listings__controller = app.controller('listings__controller', function($scope, distance__service, listing__data) {
    $scope.locations = [];

    listing__data.getUrl(distance__service.meters).then(function(data) {
    $.each(data.listings, function(i, item) {
          $scope.locations.push(item.location);
          console.log(item.location); // ** Shows Correct Object **
        });
    });
    console.log("How many inside:"+$scope.locations.length); // ** Empty - Shows 0 **
});
```

I can't seem to figure out why my `$scope.locations = []` remains empty

Comment: You fill `$scope.locations`, and you print the length of `$scope.geoLocations`.

Comment: Your `listing__data.makeRequest` is an example of the [Deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern). `$http.get` already returns a promise, so there's no need for the deferred: `return $http.get(...).then(function (resp) { return resp.data; });`

Comment: @JBNizet excuse the typo, was refactoring the code to paste here

Answer (score 2):

Even without the typo that JB Nizet mentioned, you will still see `0`, because `console.log("How many inside:"+$scope.locations.length);` gets executed *before* the callback you pass to `listing__data.getUrl(distance__service.meters).then`, since the latter is asynchronous.

Remember that when using asynchronous functions, the flow of execution doesn't follow the order of lines of your source code.

```
promise.then(function () {
    console.log('inside callback');
});
console.log('outside callback');
```

will print `outside callback` *then* `inside callback`.

Consequently, if your going to use the value you store inside `$scope.locations`, you have to do it *inside* the callback.

Comment: The geo locations inside `$scope.locations = []` need to be processed by another library. What would be the correct way to store this in the same scope so I can iterate through these values?

Comment: The other library doesn't need the data to be attached to the scope. Do all the processing inside the callback, then attach what you want to display to the scope.

Comment: I have two controllers feeding off this listing data. First controller lets call this `controller_1` lists the locations and allows the user to delete or favourite. The Second controller `controller_2` outputs the locations to a map. They both need to be bindable so in `controller_1` if i delete an object from that array, it also removes from my map. In this scenario, still everything needs to be done inside that callback you mentioned?

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xgea9u1/1/) for an example of how you can share promised data between controllers using a service.

Comment: If you have further questions about sharing data between controllers, I would suggest posting a new question (or look for already answered questions), since it is another matter entirely. This question was about writing correct asynchronous code.

Comment: Accepting the answer would be greatly appreciated. :)